# Merging rows for duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, merge, duplicates

I have an excel sheet with 300 duplicates. I need the first table to look like second table.

[image: example tables]

I don't know how to use vba.

I thought grouping by names in sql could help. I need guidance on how I could do this in excel.

I've tried with a pivot table but it doesn't exactly give me what I want.

Suggestions on how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quick and easy using [powerquery](/questions/tagged/powerquery) (`Get & Transform Data`).

Make sure your source data is formatted as a `table`, and give the first column the header "Name". Then you can use a query like:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

**EDIT**  Here's a a worked example, using your data: https://excel.solutions/53186328/

Comment: I've tried to use get&transform tab and under it power query launch editor >new source>chose excel file with duplicates>advanced editor>Used your code but changed table1 to Sheet1 but that gave me an error. What did I miss?

Comment: You didn't follow the instructions. Your data needs to be formatted as a table.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example workbook, using your sample data

Comment: Hi Olly thanks for putting in the effort to help ! I am pretty new to power query so I could not figure out the steps after making your data into a table and naming first row first column "name". From data tab these are the steps I followed: Power query launch>a screen pops up>choose a sheet that contains the table necessary>pasted the column into editor>click done>no additional table popped up. I will look into it in detail again but instructions would be great !